# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Trying to run the simplest of Azure Service bus apps:

```
using System;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration;

namespace helloapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            string connectionString = "<connection_string>";
            ServiceBusAdministrationClient client = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(connectionString);
            NamespaceProperties props = client.GetNamespacePropertiesAsync();

        }
    }
}
```

But it wont complie:

```
Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Azure.Response<Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration.NamespaceProperties>>' to 'Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration.NamespaceProperties' (CS0029) (helloapp)
```

Im new to C#, but cant find what i need to do to fix this.

I also tried this:

`NamespaceProperties props = await client.GetNamespacePropertiesAsync();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `await` operator because your method `GetNamespacePropertiesAsync` is asynchronous, and mark your `Main` method as `async` because of you are calling  `await GetNamespacePropertiesAsync` asynchronously and wait till asynchronous operation is completed. Try:

```
using System;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration;


namespace helloapp
{
    class Program
    {
        // mark this method as 'async'
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    
            string connectionString = "<connection_string>";
            ServiceBusAdministrationClient client = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(connectionString);
            NamespaceProperties props = await client.GetNamespacePropertiesAsync();
    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great, this worked, but needed one addition: using System.Threading.Tasks;